# sharing Virtualbox guest VPN connection with host using Host-only adapter

Tags: macos, virtualbox, vpn

I have a vpn connection established within a guest virtualbox VM (debian). I wish to be able to connect to a server behind the VPN via ssh directly from the host (macosX). I had **the following setup which used to work:**

[host]----------->[vbox_VM - vpn]------->[server_behind_vpn].

**host**:
my local macbook running virtualbox . The IP from my local network is 192.168.1.33.

I have added a static route so traffic to the server within the vpn to be routed via Virtualbox VM.

```
sudo route -n add -net 1.2.3.4/32 192.168.56.100
```

**Vbox VM**:
Linux Debian virtual machine.

1 x NAT adapter with IP 10.0.2.15: That gives me connectivity to internet which will allow the vpn client within the VM to connect to the vpn server.

1 x Host-only Network adapter: 192.168.56.100

Forwarding is enabled:

```
root@vbox:/home/user# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

I also have following masquarade rule in iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.56.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

The above setup used to work without issues and i was able to ssh from my local macbook directly to the server behind the vpn (via virtualbox VM) however this is not working any more.

The only way I was able to make it work was to change the Host-only adapter to Bridged Adapter. It gave my virtualbox VM an IP from my local network and i was able to ssh on the remote server via the VM without issues.

Note: I did change the route rules and masquarade rules to the new IP address in order for this to work.

It looks like routing from host to Host-Only Network has stopped working in virtualbox.

Has anyone managed to make this work using Host-Only Network adapter instead of Bridged adapter?

**Update:**
Virtualbox: 7.0.6 r155176.
macOS: 13.1 (22C65)

Comment: Host only isolates the machine. Use NAT for connections.

Comment: @John Hi. I use two adapters. One with NAT which gives vbox connection to internet and one with host-only which gives connection between the host and vbox

Comment: Which version of macOS and which version of VirtualBox? Not familiar with macOS much, but I think I remember one update forcing VBox to switch from its own virtual interfaces to the macOS provided "virtual machine networking" system...

Comment: @user1686 virtualbox: 7.0.6 r155176.  . macOS: 13.1 (22C65)

Comment: Your VPN will not work through the Host Only adapter. You need to use the NAT adapter for VPN

Comment: @John Could you further explain please? You mean the vpn connection within the VM? The VPN connection works fine within the VM since it is using the NAT adapter. My problem is routing between Host-->VM

Comment: Host Only isolates connections and it will not support VPN that way

Comment: @John If I use the NAT adapter I will not have access to quest VM....